# Easiest way to push RabbitMQ events to browser using WebSockets in Python?

Tags: python, events, browser, websocket, rabbitmq

I have an existing Python system that receives messages using Rabbit MQ.  What is the absolute easiest way to get these events pushed to a browser using WebSockets using Python?  Bonus if the solution works in all major browsers too.

Thanks,
Virgil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here  https://github.com/Gsantomaggio/rabbitmqexample I wrote an complete example that uses [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) and RabbitMQ.

You can find all the instruction from the site:

anyway ..you need:

```
pip install pika 
pip install tornado
```

First you register your rabbitmq:

```
def threaded_rmq():
    channel.queue_declare(queue="my_queue")
    logging.info('consumer ready, on my_queue')
    channel.basic_consume(consumer_callback, queue="my_queue", no_ack=True) 
    channel.start_consuming()
```

then you register your web-sockets clients:

```
class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        logging.info('WebSocket opened')
        clients.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        logging.info('WebSocket closed')
        clients.remove(self)
```

When you get a message, you can redirect it to the web-socket page.

```
def consumer_callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        logging.info("[x] Received %r" % (body,))
        # The messagge is brodcast to the connected clients
        for itm in clients:
            itm.write_message(body)
```

Comment: Great answer!  Testing this now.

Comment: how do i close this rabbitmq queue from stop consuming??

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Twisted](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autobahn), [txAMQP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txAMQP) and [Autobahn|Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autobahn) on the server to write a bridge in probably 50 lines of code, and [Autobahn|JS](http://autobahn.ws/js/) on the browser side. Autobahn implements WebSocket, and [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) on top, which provides you with Publish & Subscribe (as well as Remote Procedure Calls) over WebSocket.

*When using raw WebSocket you would have to invent your own Publish & Subscribe over WebSocket - since I guess that is what you are after: extending the AMQP PubSub to the Web. Or you could check out STOMP.*

Disclaimer: I am original author of WAMP and Autobahn.